# Understanding Spring Boot Usage and Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, configuration, spring-boot

I am trying to understand how to configure spring boot. All these [tutorials](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html) and [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html) make reference to something called `application.properties`. I'm assuming that that is a file and if so, where does it go and is there a template to set it up?

I would like to see all the different configurations I can specify and pick and choose which ones I need.

I just setup logback in my program and would like to set the logging level. The tutorial says spring boot already provides a base config like so:

```
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG"/>
</configuration>
```

But I have no idea where I would put that. In the application.properties? In the pom.xml?

Comment: One suggestion: use STS you can get at spring.io/tools, it will create an application.properties in the right location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stick the application.properties in src/main/resources.  I actually prefer to use .yml files which is an alternative format.  You can find many spring boot properties (including logging properties) here:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Spring Boot will auto configure any dependency you declare in Maven with sensible defaults.  You can override any of the default settings in your application file.

Comment: very helpful. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can have a look at a complete step by step explanation here
https://shakeelosmani.wordpress.com/2017/02/13/step-by-step-spring-boot-hibernate-crud-web-application-tutorial/